# Get the server name from socket

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

I try to edit the mallory proxy which can be used to sniff SSL-traffic. However it has problems with servers using connecting to a server behing e.g. CloudFlare because one can't get the real certificate but the one from the CloudFlare server in the front.

Due to this I wanted to use the server_hostname option from SSLContext.wrap_socket(). But for this I need to get the destination server's name from the Python socket object. However the only function I know to retreive this is getpeername() but this returns only the destination's ip. Does someone know a way to get the server name from a socket, too?

Comment: It this for HTTP? In this case you --unfortunately-- need to extract the ``Host:`` from HTTP headers. The ``server_name`` argument for python ssl is for SNI (server name indication) exactly because the name of the target host cannot be determined from the connection ...

Comment: It's for HTTP and HTTPS. This solution is a little bit unsatisfactory as I need to do this before the real connection is established in order to fake the certificate.

Comment: Then you probably need to grab the server name from the incoming SSL socket via ``SSLContext.set_servername_callback()``. However note availability on your python version: http://bugs.python.org/issue8109 ...

Comment: Thx for your suggestion, that could may be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution dhke suggested in the comments, to call [`set_servername_callback()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.set_servername_callback), is indeed the solution I searched for as one can see [here](https://github.com/akheron/cpython/blob/2e9128646429d08d3d144bd85805be33f1146b5f/Lib/test/test_urllib2_localnet.py#L575). However it doesn't work to use this in mallory but that's another topic.